# Why do I get a error in openCV ::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale?

Tags: python, opencv

**so basically I am writing a program in python using openCV that can detect cars and then turns the picture into a gray-scale image. However, it shows an error when I run the code.**

**This is the error**

: line 19, in 
cars = car_tracker.detectMultiScale(black_n_white)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\cascadedetect.cpp:1689: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function 'cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale'

Here is my code:

```
import cv2

#These are our images
img_file ='car.jpg'

#This will be the result of the algorithm after it is trained
classifier_file = 'car_detector.xml'

#create opencv image
img = cv2.imread(img_file)

#create a car classifier
car_tracker = cv2.CascadeClassifier(classifier_file)

#convert it to black and white first cuz it makes it 3x faster for the algorithm
black_n_white = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#detect cars
cars = car_tracker.detectMultiScale(black_n_white)

#display the image with car spotted
cv2.imshow('car detector', black_n_white)

#this makes it wait 
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Use full paths for your files.

Answer (score 0):

The error is thrown since OpenCV cannot find your xml file, probably you wrote the wrong path. A good way to check whether your file was loaded properly is to first initialize the classifier (`clf = cv2.CascadeClassifier()`) and then check if `clf.load(filename)` returns True.